# how to draw route from userlocation to some pin in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mkannotationview, userlocation

I am implementing map based application in iPhone sdk. I want to give functionality in map view like Google maps directoins. means is at some location from that he selects one pin from multiple pins from `MKPinAnnotationView`. is it possible that user can get direction from his current location to selected pin location in `MapView`? user can select any aanonations from that he can get directions in some way of line to his current location to pin location. [i have get some idea from here](http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=65)

but this all was some static data [you can download this example.](http://spitzkoff.com/craig/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/maplinesandannotations1.zip)
[here also apple example.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Breadcrumb/Listings/Classes_CrumbPathView_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010048-Classes_CrumbPathView_m-DontLinkElementID_8) but this example is only for track & draw line for user movement.
is it possible that user can get direction from his current location to selected pin location in `MapView`?

Comment: does any body have any idea about this? i have found the solution from here  code.google.com/p/octomapkit but it is not working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got all side idea [from here](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/MapKit-Route-Directions)
this can be useful for other developers also.
 i have found some other examples also that can be also useful for other developers just google. you will find [this is polyline link](https://github.com/leviathan/nvpolyline) for user current location use [this apple code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CurrentAddress/Listings/Classes_MapViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009469-Classes_MapViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6)

Comment: hi, I am implementing the nvpolyline for the route drawing but now I can't implement custom annotation pin, please suggest me the way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can send a query to google maps api using your current location and the selected annotation location. When google responds with the route, you will use that polyline decoder method to decode the data and draw the route on your map view.

Comment: yes i have found some source code from here http://code.google.com/p/octomapkit/ but i have get some errors while implementing this api. `APp/OctoRouteParserTest.m:21:0 OctoRouteParserTest.m:21:26: error: OCMock/OCMock.h: No such file or directory` i am trying to solve this.

Comment: hey dude, have you checked out this URL.? have you get any idea about this error?. i think this is file missing error. but i have tried at all steps that here explained in URL.

Comment: Nope. That error seems self explanatory. You should be able resolve it. And if not, just write your own code, you have all the pieces between what Inder and I have mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

Here is [Google direction api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/). Read it and use it.

For test purpose you can check this request 
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=28.459497,77.026638&destination=28.435600,77.009997&sensor=true 
**And use [JSON Viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) to see the json response.**